# What happens when we create object of one class in another class in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, memory-management

Let's say, When we create an object of one class(`A` class) in another class(`B` class), Will the object of `A` class be created each time when we create object of `B` class? How does memory get allocated here?

Example code snippet below;

```
class Test 
{ 
  int x, y; 
} 

class Test2
{ 
  int a; 
  int b; 
  Test c = new Test();
} 

public class Main 
{ 
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  { 
    Test2 t1 = new Test2(); 
    t1.a = 10; 
    t1.b = 20; 
    t1.c.x = 30; 
    t1.c.y = 40; 

    Test2 t2 = new Test2();

    System.out.println(t1.a + " " + t1.b + " " + 
                    t1.c.x + " " + t1.c.y); 
    System.out.println(t2.a + " " + t2.b + " " + 
                    t2.c.x + " " + t2.c.y); 
    t2.a = 100; 
    t2.c.x = 300; 

    System.out.println(t1.a + " " + t1.b + " " + 
                    t1.c.x + " " + t1.c.y); 
    System.out.println(t2.a + " " + t2.b + " " + 
                    t2.c.x + " " + t2.c.y); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: `Test c = new Test();` will definitely create a new instance everytime the constructor of `Test2` is called. You could just skip the initialization of `Test c`, but then you would have to take care of that attribute being initialized when needed.

Comment: Yes, as your `Test` object is initialized in an instance block in `Test2`, a new instance of `Test` will be created and allocated to the heap each time you create a new instance of `Test2`.